# google maps API 3 zooms out on fitBounds

Tags: google-maps-api-3, fitbounds

I've run into a problem where calling map.fitBounds seems to zoom out. I'm trying to use the backbone.js router to save the map bounds in the url. I want to be able to bookmark the url and later have the map look exactly the same.

I noticed calling `map.fitBounds(map.getBounds())` in the console will always zoom out. Where as I would like it to not change the map.

Is this normal behaviour? How can I enforce this so the map will look the same from one step to the next?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51270624/434697 worked for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This problem of Google Map API was discussed few times. See:

- [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3117)
- [google-maps-js-api-v3 group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/ed2806b940a43b11/c0ebb7e1d1ef73d6)

Function `map.fitBounds()` sets the viewport to contain the bounds. But `map.getBounds()` function returns the viewport bounds with some extra margin (note that this is normal behaviour and no bug). The enlarged bounds no longer fits in the previous viewport, so the map zooms out.

A simple solution to your problem is to use the map center and the zoom level instead. See functions `map.getCenter()`, `map.setCenter()`, `map.getZoom()` and `map.setZoom()`.

Comment: I took me more then 16 hours to land here. Even if this is no bug, there should some work around for those who are attempting to do this.

Answer (score 18):

For people seeing this question in 2018, [Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#LatLngBounds) now supports a second `padding` argument that specifies the amount of padding to include around the bounds you specify.

To avoid zooming out, simply just call `fitBounds` with a padding of `0`. For this example it would be `map.fitBounds(map.getBounds(), 0)`

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem when after initializing the map called `map.fitBounds(...)`. The behaviour I encountered was that if the `fitBounds` method was called a few seconds after the map was initialized then no problem (the zoom was appropriate).
So first I started to call the `fitBounds` method after the map was loaded, which on google maps translates to when the map is `idle`.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
   var bounds = //define bounds...
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

This actually works, however the `idle` event is triggered almost constantly. And if there is any change to the map (drag, zoom, etc...) when this change stops, the map will fit the bounds again...
The problem is that calling the method only once does **not** work (either with a boolean to check if was already called, or with `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce` because the first time the map is idle it still "isn't ready" for the bounds to be fitted. (From experience).

So my **solution** was to trigger the `fitBounds` on a different event. Instead of `idle` which is called too early for the `fitBounds` method, the event `tilesloaded` actually gets the job done (only called once)!

***Solution:***

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
   var bounds = //define bounds...
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

## Fixing this problem in 2017

Shrink the bounding box slightly before sending it to `map.fitBounds()`.

Here's a function to shrink a bounding box:

```js
// Values between 0.08 and 0.28 seem to work
// Any lower and the map will zoom out too much
// Any higher and it will zoom in too much
var BOUNDS_SHRINK_PERCENTAGE = 0.08; // 8%

/**
 * @param  {google.maps.LatLngLiteral} southwest
 * @param  {google.maps.LatLngLiteral} northeast
 * @return {Array[google.maps.LatLngLiteral]}
 */
function slightlySmallerBounds(southwest, northeast) {
  function adjustmentAmount(value1, value2) {
    return Math.abs(value1 - value2) * BOUNDS_SHRINK_PERCENTAGE;
  }

  var latAdjustment = adjustmentAmount(northeast.lat, southwest.lat);
  var lngAdjustment = adjustmentAmount(northeast.lng, southwest.lng);

  return [
    {lat: southwest.lat + latAdjustment, lng: southwest.lng + lngAdjustment},
    {lat: northeast.lat - latAdjustment, lng: northeast.lng - lngAdjustment}
  ]
}
```

Use it like this:

```js
// Ensure `southwest` and `northwest` are objects in google.maps.LatLngLiteral form:
// southwest == {lat: 32.79712, lng: -117.13931}
// northwest == {lat: 32.85020, lng: -117.09356}

var shrunkBounds = slightlySmallerBounds(southwest, northeast);
var newSouthwest = shrunkBounds[0];
var newNortheast = shrunkBounds[1];

// `map` is a `google.maps.Map`
map.fitBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLngBounds(newSouthwest, newNortheast)
);
```

I have an app doing the same thing as [codr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82748/codr): saving the current map bounds in the URL, and initializing the map from the URL bounds upon refresh. This solution works wonderfully for that.

## Why does this work?

Google Maps essentially does this when `fitBounds()` is called:

1. Center the map on the centerpoint of the given bounding box.
2. Zoom in to the highest zoom level where the viewport would *contain* the given bounds *inside* of the viewport box.

If the bounds given would *exactly* match the viewport, Google Maps doesn't consider that as "containing" the bounds, so it zooms out one more level.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this behavior when using `fitBounds()` on a hidden map view (using a front-end rendering framework, like Angular). Because this was a mobile view, I was showing a list of locations first, and was populating the markers on a hidden map as the list was loading (a concurrent load). So when the user wants to view the map, and they switch the segment view/tab/whatever, the map would show with the markers already loaded and in view. But this bugged out and zoomed to show the complete world in the map.

```
<div [hidden]="view !== 'map'>
    <google-map></google-map>
</div>
```

`fitBounds()` needs the map to be loaded in the view because it uses the maps dimensions in order to resize the map. If the map is hidden, it zooms the map until the complete map is shown.

The solution was simple: when the view was switched, call `fitBounds()` again.

```
<button (click)="showMap()">Show Map</button>

public showMap() {
    this.view = 'map';
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (typeof this.map !== 'undefined') this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds);
    });
}
```

Note: I wrapped a `setTimeout` around the `fitBounds()` call so that Angular can finish the lifecycle and render the map before it is called.

Comment: +1 Ran into this exact scenario and this is the fix that worked for me. I'd note that in my case I just used a `setTimeout` and waited 500ms because `this.map` was already defined on my page. The issue only happened when doing a `show()`, `hide()`, then `show()` again. The half-second delay was enough of a wait time to let everything reset within the map.

Comment: I'm using a hidden map on a Django site and this was the problem. I found that the map had to be literally visible before `fitBounds()` would work correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this problem too.  My solution is to compare `map.getBounds()` to what I am setting the bounds to; if they are the same, I'm skipping the `map.fitBounds()` call.

Answer (score 0):

I was hit with the same problem and @Tomik's answer helped me resolving it. Here is the snippets of the code I used.

To save the previous zoom and center.

```
const lastMapZoom = this.map.getZoom();
const lastMapCenter = this.map.getCenter();
```

To set the values back.

```
this.map.setCenter(lastMapCenter);
this.map.setZoom(lastMapZoom);
```