# Google Maps API V3 saving / restoring bounds in local storage

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to save the bounds of my google map as it moves in local storage so that I can reopen the app and have the map at the exact same place. However, every time the page reloads, it seems to be centered on the same point, but slightly zooms out each time.

Is there a bug that is causing this in their bounds calculations, or am I utilizing their data wrong.

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hu65m/

Zoom in on a location, click run again and it will reload, but being a little zoomed out.

```
map.fitBounds(getBounds(), {
    animate: false
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    console.log("idle");
    saveBounds(map.getBounds());
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [goole maps API 3 zooms out on fitBounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170023/goole-maps-api-3-zooms-out-on-fitbounds)

Comment: Thank you kind internet citizen, I searched for a while on Google but that didn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

fitBounds will make sure your bounds fit on the map, which means it will be bigger than the actual bounds.

You can do it by saving your map center and zoom level instead. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/erV6Q/

```
var center = map.getCenter();
var zoom = map.getZoom();

localStorage.mapCenter = JSON.stringify(center);
localStorage.mapZoom = zoom;
```