# google maps v3: center of bounds is different from center of the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How is it possible that `map.getCenter()` might be different from `map.getBounds().getCenter()`?

```
> cragMap.getCenter()
> Q {d: 13.823563748466814, e: 0, toString: function, b: function, equals: function…}
> cragMap.getBounds().getCenter()
> Q {d: 5.9865924355766005, e: 0, toString: function, b: function, equals: function…}
```

This happens in my case and prevents me from coding one particular feature. Any idea what is the cause of this?

Comment: Presumably this is because getCenter() on the map object itself is applied on a global scale, whereas getCenter() on a LatLngBounds object will compute the center of a limited space

Comment: And with lower zoom level difference is rising.

Comment: possible duplicate of [goole maps API 3 zooms out on fitBounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170023/goole-maps-api-3-zooms-out-on-fitbounds)

Comment: @geocodezip: not a duplicate. Read the question carefully please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is caused by latitude non-linearity of mercartor projection. `map.getBounds().getCenter()` returns average of latDim and lngDim. But that average is usually different from the center of the map because to the north and south the scale of latitude changes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Any suggestions on how to work around this or in other words how to get the calculated map center for bounding box?